# Is there a list of iOS apps that can be called using custom URLs?

Tags: ios

It is possible to launch your own app via custom URL scheme as described at http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html for example. Is there a list of the apps that use this mechanism somewhere already? A list of custom URLs available to date? If you have or know an app that uses this mechanism, adding it here will also help.

Answer (score 2):

See http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes

Comment: I think this is the most reliable one

Answer (score 1):

http://www.onemillionappschemes.com, an open source Custom URL scheme site where you can contribute URLS (by scanning your iTunes library) and where you can pick up everything that has been found so far